# Best way to combine categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, descriptive-statistics, categorical-encoding

I have two categorical variables measuring outdoor time during winter and summer. As I am interested in the overall outdoor time during the whole year, I am thinking about combining the variables.

However, the responses are categorical, both variables do have same responses:

```
Time spent outdoor (Winter or Summer):

 - Three or more hours
 - One to two hours
 - Less than one hour
 - Not at all
```

What is the best way to combine the variables? I was thinking about representing the responses by numbers, i.e., One to two hours = 1.5h. And then calculate the mean. But I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Why bin the amount of time spent outdoors? Doing so equates one hour and two hours yet considers two hours and 2:01 to be very different.

Comment: Yes that's true, but these questions were part of a bigger questionnaire and the outdoor time wasn't a primary focus.